# SQL Server Migration Asistant (SSMA) doesn't recognise MySQL Columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-migration-assi

I am trying to migrate my MySQL DB to MsSQL.However, as you can see in the picture SQL Server Management Assistant cant recognise MySQL table columns.

[image: SSMA problem]

alternative link https://ibb.co/HXxKMBx

Comment: What datatype is that column?

Comment: int or small int or bigint none of them is recognised

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/ssma/mysql/project-settings-type-mapping-mysqltosql?view=sql-server-2017.     And blog can be help you : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssma/2011/02/07/mysql-to-sql-server-migration-how-to-use-ssma/

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/migrate-mysql-tables-sql-server-using-sql-server-migration-assistant-ssma-ssis/